# Horizontally and vertically Totals in RDLC Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, crosstab

I am using `RDLC Reports in VS 2015 with SQL Server 2014`. I have a `Matrix` Report in which i need totals both horizontally and vertically. DataSet have Columns `Item,Month and Amount`. I need below report format.

[image]

I have used `Add Total Row/Column` but it gives me wrong results. What should be issue.? Any Help..

Comment: Do you have an item row group and month column group?

Comment: Yes i have a row Group of Item by there Categories and Column Group of Month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the required totals using scoped `SUM` expressions. Supposing you have created the needed rows and columns groups, use a matrix with the following data arrangement.

[image]

> Note in your case it is `[Sum(Amount)]` instead of `[Sum(Value)]` in
>   my case.

For showing the totals just add the row and the column outside the groups `item` and `Month` respectively.

Select the `[item]` row (second row) and right click, go to `insert row` and select `outside group - below`.

[image]

To add the column select the `[month]` column (second column), right click it and select `insert column` then `outside group - right`.

[image]

Now add these expressions in the highlighted cells in red, check the first image.

1: `=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value,"Month")`

2: `=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value,"item")`

It will produce the following matrix:

[image]

Let me know if my answer helps you.

Comment: Thats great, it solved my 50% of problem. How to sum Column outside `ColumnGroup` i.e after `Total Column` i have `AverageQty` column, which is outside the `ColumnGroup Month`, how can i get its Total at `TotalRow`.

Comment: Do you need to get the sum of averages or the total average in the total row?

Comment: `AverageQty` is an other column which comes from Database, i have already calculated it item wise. Only need to Total of all averages in `RowTotal`. `AverageQty` is outside `ColumnGroup` after Total Column.

Comment: Try using this expression in the total cell: `Avg(Fields!AverageQty.Value, "DataSetName")` replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the cell you want the total in and choose add total then choose if you want it totaled on the column or the rows. So this will work for both columns and rows.

Comment: I have already applied this, but it gives me wrong totals. :(