# How do I add a rowNumber in RDLC that counts all the products and not the materials as well(they are grouped by products)?

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

At the NR column I want to have 1, 2, 3 etc and not 4, 8(counting all the materials) or 4, 4(counting all the materials for each product, this happens when I do RowNumber("GroupName"))

[image: This is how it looks when I add RowNumber(nothing)]

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791348/horizontally-and-vertically-totals-in-rdlc-matrix?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am not trying to achieve any sum of products. My point is I want the NR column to count all the products. So instead of having the 4. and 8. (as you can see in the picture above) I want it to show 1. and 2. cuz there are only 2 products there.

Comment: Same principal except instead of using SUM() you use the function COUNT()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.